# REST API: What should be status code if incorrect source is passed by the client?

Tags: rest, http, http-status-codes

In our API, we ask mandatorily for client source in the http request header with values as:

1. 1-Desktop
2. 2-Mobile
3. 3-Apps

What should be status code returned if we get header input other than 1,2,3.

Should it be bad request or unauthorized?

Comment: Most common response in these cases is 400. But 422 also works. Don't use 401 unless someone is not logged in or does not have a valid auth token.

Comment: You could try 415 " Unsupported Media Type" More about it [here](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html)

Comment: Mandating a specific client type is IMHO an anti pattern and has nothing to do with "REST".